# How can I change the size of a scene to resize nodes within the scene that are bound to the size of the scene?

Tags: java, javafx, binding, scene

I have a scene that contains several child nodes in various layout containers. All of the nodes are bound to the size of the scene. The Scene class's sizes are both a ReadOnlyDoubleProperty. How can I change the size of the whole thing so that all of the nodes will resize to the new size? Would it be possible to simply change the size of the layout containers (which are bound to the size of the scene)?

I am open other suggestions that might solve this problem in a different way.

Comment: You can change the size of the stage containing the scene.

Comment: @James_D Hmmm, looking at the documentation, the width/height properties of Stage include window decorations. Is there any way to get the size of the decorations or change the stage to a size that doesn't include the window decorations?

Comment: Not that I know of. But of course you could increase the width/height by a fixed amount (`stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth()+delta);`). "All of the nodes are bound to the size of the scene" sounds a bit strange, btw. The layout panes typically manage all that for you. If you use the usual layout approach, I think calling `stage.sizeToScene()` will size the stage so that the scene is sized to give all nodes their preferred size.

Comment: @James_D I'm creating minesweeper, and all of the cells are Rectangles calculate their size based on the size of the scene (so that the game is resizable). I'll try your suggestion with the fixed amount increase. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you could just use a `GridPane` with column constraints and row constraints set to equal width/height (using percentages). Then the resizing would basically all be done for you. You could just use a `Pane` instead of a `Rectangle`, and use `setFillWidth(true)` and `setFillHeight(true)` on the column/row constraints. Probably you should rewrite your question to focus on the problem you are trying to solve, instead of the solution you are trying to use to solve it.